# Datatype for store month and year only in the mysql table?

Tags: mysql, database-design

How to store the month and year only in the mysql table and which datatype is preferable ?

Needed Output : December / 2016

Comment: Do you want to know the way of storing date to mysql ?

Comment: Instead mm-yyyy  this one ??

Comment: Now,I store as varchar with 12/2016 how to display as December / 2016

Comment: Yes i am asking storing datatype ? Please any one help . . .

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have stored as mm/yyyy so to display you need to lpad (in to be sure that you are always working with 7 characters, split, work out the month name and then concat

```
set @dt = '12/2016';

select concat(
            (case when substring(lpad(@dt,7,'0'),1,2) = 12 then 'Dec' 
                when substring(lpad(@dt,7,'0'),1,2) = 1 then 'Jan'
            end ),'/',
        substring(lpad(@dt,7,'0'),4,4))     formatted
```

I leave you to add all the months to the case statement.

Result

```
+-----------+
| formatted |
+-----------+
| Dec/2016  |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd store it as your favorite [date and time type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-types.html) and then manipulate the output with [`DATE_FORMAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format). You could also format the output in your application code rather than as part of the MySQL query.

This way you're leveraging the native date datatype, so you can do actual date math through queries, and MySQL is happy to format the output however you desire.